# Why does SUM totals show NULL when using group by clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is some test Data so you can see my data and results:

```
create table test_table
(employee nvarchar (50),
job nvarchar (50),
phase nvarchar (50),
date datetime,
totaltime real)

insert into test_table (employee,job,phase, date, totaltime)

values ('1234','1-100','2-0000','1/1/2015', 7),
 ('1234',NULL,'2-0000','1/1/2015', 7)

 SELECT employee,date,job, phase,
(case 
when job = NULL then SUM(CAST(ISNULL(TotalTime,0)as NUMERIC(36,2)))
when job > '0' then SUM(CAST(ISNULL(TotalTime,0)as NUMERIC(36,2))) 
end)
FROM test_table
group by employee,job,phase,date
```

Here are my results -

Employee , Date ,                  Job  ,   Phase  , TotalTime

1234,  2015-01-01 ,  NULL,   2-0000  , NULL

1234,  2015-01-01 ,  1-100,  2-0000, 7.00

Why does my total time show as NULL when the job is NULL?

Answer (score 4):

Because `Job` is never **equal** to `NULL`. You should be using `job IS NULL` instead

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `IS NULL` instead of `= NULL`. Nothing is equal to `NULL` (not even another `NULL`), so  `NULL = NULL` returns `null` (unknown), and your `case` statement falls through to the "default" value of `null`.

```
 SELECT employee,date,job, phase,
(case 
when job IS NULL then SUM(CAST(ISNULL(TotalTime,0)as NUMERIC(36,2)))
when job > '0' then SUM(CAST(ISNULL(TotalTime,0)as NUMERIC(36,2))) 
end)
FROM test_table
group by employee,job,phase,date
```

Comment: `NULL = NULL` isn't actually `FALSE`, it's unknown (which is not `TRUE`)

Answer (score 0):

Addendum, if you want to select the `Job` which is not null. You just negate it which is `job IS NOT NULL`.